# Google Web Fonts not displaying correctly in Chrome on Windows 7

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, windows-7, google-font-api

I'm having a problem with a Wordpress based site I'm building on: In Chrome, on Windows 7, the body text on the sites' homepage is set to display as a Google Font. However the last line of the text is displaying as the default sans-serif font.

I have thought about asking about this on Wordpress.org but as the problem is confined to one browser on one OS (albeit the most commonly used browser on the most commonly used OS, natch) thought better to ask here. Have been looking all day and not seen anyone else have the same problem.

It's the latest version of Chrome and there is no problem in IE, Firefox, Opera etc. No problems (as yet...) on any other platforms at all.

There don't appear to be any problems with any other Google Fonts used in the site.

The site is currently hosted at http://best.videofeet.com

Upon inspection of the source there is no apparent reason why it would render like this.

I'm stumped.

Here's a link to an image of the problem (From VirtualBox on Mac - the only means I have available to me to replicate the bug as described by the client): https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0mA7.jpg

Comment: I managed to replicate it on XP as well, just FYI (I don't have Win 7 as a test machine). I did fix it by using developer tools, and editing the <p> tag causing the issue by removing the <br> and elipsis at the end. I have no idea what is causing it though. Very cool bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll take a stab at answering this now I've had a tinker. It looks like Josefin Sans does not have a glyph for ellipsis (…), so Chrome is swapping out that line. There are other people experiencing this with other Google fonts:

- https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=204
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/a-problem-with-ellipsis-the-google-font-story

The lack of ellipsis can be [tested here](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Josefin%20Sans)

Either swap the ellipsis for three periods and risk the wrath of typophiles, or change the font I'm afraid.

Before and after image showing the paragraph tag with the ellipsis removed in developer tools here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA6gC.jpg

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed it! It's a strange one because in WP it was entered as three periods, but the browser was reading it as a glyph instead. The ellipsis was the clients', but I think it scans better as a full stop anyway (as well as an ellipsis looking like it could be a 'read more link'). I'm sure the client will agree with some gentle persuasion.

Comment: Glad to help. Mark this as the correct solution if you are happy with it so I get my fake internet points.